# Changing the appearance of a countdown timer when goal is reached?

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdown

I have built a simple countdown timer, and am wondering how I can make it so once the countdown is finished I can change the timer to a div that tells the user the countdown is completed? Currently it will just add negatives to countdown like this:

As it counts down:

```
[ 01 ][ 01 ][ 10 ][ 30 ]
 days hours  mins  secs
```

Once it reaches past time limit:

```
[ 00 ][ -01 ][ -10 ][ -30 ]
 days hours  mins  secs
```

I'm not really sure where to even start on this, but here is how my timer is set in HTML

**Timer HTML:**

```
<div class="timer">
      <div><div id="d"></div>days</div>
      <div><div id="h"></div>hours</div>
      <div><div id="m"></div>min</div>
      <div><div id="s"></div>sec</div>
</div>
```

**and my JS functions:**

```
// vars for current year
var current = new Date();

//Your current year
var current_year = current.getFullYear();

//Next year
var next_year = current_year + 1;

// Date you will count down to
// You can change the 'current_year' to 'next year' as well if you were counting down to someing in 2016
var target_date = new Date("july 4, " + current_year).getTime();

// Vars for units of time
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// Get the elements that will hold the numbers.
var $days = document.getElementById("d");
var $hours = document.getElementById("h");
var $minutes = document.getElementById("m");
var $seconds = document.getElementById("s");

// Calculate the countdown clock and set the HTML.
function update() {
  // Find the amount of "seconds" between now and target.
  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

  // Do some time calcs
  days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

  hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

  minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
  seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

  // Format the number strings and put them in the elements.
  $days.innerHTML = pad(days, 2);
  $hours.innerHTML = pad(hours, 2);
  $minutes.innerHTML = pad(minutes, 2);
  $seconds.innerHTML = pad(seconds, 2);
}

// update the HTML
// or else your boxes will be blank
update();

// update every 1 second.
setInterval(update, 1000);


// If num has less than size digits, add enough 0s to the front.
function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num+"";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}
```

And a **[codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/yNvJrx)** to further help explain.

I imagine I would need something along the lines of..

- A `var` to represent 'completed'
- A function to say once the `var` completed is satisfied, change the class of `timer`?

I'm really not sure, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want to know is

> Is the countdown is before or after `now`.

First put your `interval` in a var like this:

```
var countdownInterval = setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Second, in your `update()` function, add:

```
if(target_date <= Date.now()) {
    clearInterval(countdownInterval);
    document.querySelector(".timer").innerHTML = "Countdown ended!"
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me, all I had to do was change the `myInterval` in the `clearInterval()` function to `countdownInterval`.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Yes, you need to set a var with the `setInterval` function inside if you want to stop this interval in your code. Perfect! Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

In your update() function you merely need to check to see if seconds_left is <= 0, and as you suggested, update the class.

I have updated your [code](http://jsfiddle.net/xco145nt/3/) to include a shorter timer for testing, and a class addition.

```
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000; // Unchanged

if ( seconds_left <= 0 ) {
    // Change class here
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('timer')[0];
    ele.classList.add('completed');
}
```

Comment: I feel this answer is better as it uses an existing variable. Can easily add clearInterval() but stopping the timer was not a requirement of the question. Since the OP updated the Codepen in the question, here is a copy of the original code: http://jsfiddle.net/3raxrq5u/1/

Answer (score 0):

First, declare an interval identifier, which then serve to remove the timer:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Then, you can verify if the time is over, and you can show the message.

```
var all_seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
if(all_seconds_left <= 0){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    document.querySelector("#myResultDIV").innerHTML = "All done!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `update` function, you can add this:

```
if(target_date <= Date.now()) {
    // done!
}
```

You can then style the `timer` div however you'd like, but the simplest could be something like this:

```
var timer = document.querySelectorAll('.timer');
timer.innerHTML = 'Done!';
```

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to get it to change the timer